# Structs unpack and pack changes data

Tags: python, struct, subprocess, pipe, pack

I am currently trying to pack some data in a script "p1.py", and then unpack it in another script "p2.py" via a pipe. The pipe communication works perfectly, and I'm able to send data between the two scripts. However, upon unpacking the data gets changed. In this case, I do this in script "p2.py" in order to pack the data and send it over to the "p1.py" script:

```
COMMAND_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">fB3s")

packed_data = struct.pack(">fB3s",29.1,1,b'3s')
print(packed_data)
#lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(packed_data)
#print(lateral_airspeed_input)
```

As we can see, I print "packed_data" which is packed to be a float, a byte and then 3 bytes. Now if I simply print the packed data to my terminal, I get this output:

b'A\xe8\xcc\xcd\x013s\x00'

Which is simply the packed form of the 29.1,1 and 3 bytes. If I uncomment the last two lines, lateral_airspeed_input will be 29.1  -indicating that the unpacking and packing works, as I can pack the data and unpack and get the same data after unpacking.

Now, here's where it get interesting. When I bring in the other script, I do the same thing as seen here:

```
        cmd = pilot.stdout.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
        #print(cmd)
        if len(cmd) != COMMAND_STRUCT.size:
            result = CRASHED  # The pilot process must have exited
            break
        lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(cmd)
        print(lateral_airspeed_input)
        lateral_airspeed = max(-30.0, min(30.0, lateral_airspeed_input))
        drop_package_commanded = bool(drop_package_commanded_byte)
```

Here, the packed data is read onto the variable cmd, and then cmd is unpacked to the lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte and the _ variables. Ideally, if we print lateral_airspeed_input we should be getting 29.1. However, I get 7.713289749049545e+20 upon printing it. However, if I just print cmd straight away, I get this:

b"b'A\xe8\"
b'xcc\xcd\'
b'x013s\x0'
b"0'\r\n"

which looks similar to the packed data from before - when I was just using one py script. For some reason, the packed data gets all these extra , b" and 0\r\n things on it. I think this is messing up the communication and I was wondering if there's a way to avoid this. I'd rather avoid this than stripping the codes off the lines.

Thanks for the help. I am using subprocess pipes to manage the communication between the two scripts, and simply running the subprocess through my windows cmd.

Comment: The sending script seems to be doing something along the lines of `print(repr(cmd))` rather than just `print(cmd)`.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm not too sure what to do. I've noticed if I change the numbers in the sending script, the receiving script gets a new set of bytes (just printing out the packed version on data coming from the sending script) but when I unpack to the variables the variables always have the same value. (Even though the Packed version of the data changes, unpacking to lateral_airspeed_input does not change the value. It's always the same

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response - it's much appreciated. I think you are right and the way it's printing is messing up the unpacking. I tried to do print(cmd, end = '') and this is the output I got:
b"b'A\\xe8\\"b'xcc\\xcd\\'b'x013s\\x0'b"0'\r\n"

as compared to:

b'A\xe8\xcc\xcd\x013s\x00'

When I try to print the lateral_airspeed_input (the unpacked data) I still get the same numbers as before (incorrect ones). I also tried using sys.stdout but same results. Would really appreciate some help! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I rethought my original answer.  I'm trying to get to the point of reproducing the issue.  If you can get to the point of generating a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I think it might go a long way to helping you get a full answer.  Currently the code you've shared has some unreferenced data like `pilot` that prevents me from being able to run the code as provided.

Comment: Ah thank you, makes sense! (Sorry I'm new to coding/stack overflow but thanks for the guidance!) Hopefully my comment on your answer will provide more info needed to reproduce the problem. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to help you get an actual answer to your issue.  If you are able to provide a fully running example (something like the full .py scripts complete with all the necessary `import` statements and everything that I've pasted below in my answer) that people can just copy/paste and run, it makes it much more likely that you'll get a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, your sender script is printing the representation of the string. I.e. instead of the byte sequence `41 e8 cc cd ...` (`A..`) you get `62 21 41 ...` (`b"A\...`).

Also, `print` and `stdout` are by default working in text mode. I.e. you will get in trouble with raw binary data. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) says that you can use the underlying buffer of `stdio` to send binary data:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(packed_data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

You must use `flush` to actually send the data. Otherwise it would only be written when a newline character (`0x0d`) is encountered.

Also, if you do this, make sure that the stdout is not actually printed to screen. Otherwise your terminal will be messed up rather quickly.

Vice versa, you should use binary reading in the receiver script: `cmd = sys.stdin.buffer.read()`.

Comment: This works, finally managed to write to the stdout and read it on the other side! Thanks so much. 

I'm having a little issue on the reading side now on the second script. My previous issue was getting the second script to write to the first script (your solution solved that issue :)) Now I am trying to get the second script to receive from the first script. In the second script, I use cmd = sys.stdin.buffer.read() however this bottlenecks the code and nothing runs for some reason

Comment: Within the first script, the following lines of code are relevant to the sending of the the packet:
pilot = subprocess.Popen(args.pilot, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pilot.stdin.write(TELEMETRY_STRUCT.pack(int(loop_count * DT_SEC * 1e3).......)

where ... represents some more variables that it's packing and writing to stdin. On the receiving end I do: 
telemetry = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
print(telemetry)

however, this crashes the whole thing :P Do you see anything wrong with this tactic?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the whole code. First of all, of course the script can either wait for input (``.read`` call) or calculate + send output, not both at once. Let's assume that your pilot only outputs something in reaction to input. :-) Then, again you must ``flush()`` pilot's stdin in order to actually have the data send. Also, ``print(telemetry)`` must fail, because it prints to stdout, which is piped back. For debug output, you could print to ``sys.stderr`` to have it appear on console, or write into a log file instead.

Comment: Hmmm trying it out but not sure if it works. I have posted a new question with the full error and code on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909753/stdin-and-stdout-in-parralel.

Would greatly appreciate some assistance, thanks for the help thus far! It's been very helpful in getting my sanity back :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put together a sample based on what you provided.

This is script p1.py:

```
import struct

COMMAND_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">fB3s")

packed_data = struct.pack(">fB3s",29.1,1,b'3s')
print(packed_data)
```

This is script p2.py:

```
import struct
import sys

COMMAND_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">fB3s")
cmd = sys.stdin.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
#print(cmd)
if len(cmd) != COMMAND_STRUCT.size:
    sys.exit(1)
lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(cmd)
print(lateral_airspeed_input)
lateral_airspeed = max(-30.0, min(30.0, lateral_airspeed_input))
drop_package_commanded = bool(drop_package_commanded_byte)
```

If I run it like this, I believe I get the expected result:

```
%> python2 p1.py | python2 p2.py

29.1000003815
```

That seems like the desired result.  Can you elaborate on what's different in your scenario vs. this small example?

**UPDATE**

Following on your previous comment, I made a new script `p3.py` that looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import struct
import sys

COMMAND_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">fB3s")
pilot = subprocess.Popen(['python2','./p1.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd = pilot.stdout.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
#cmd = sys.stdin.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
#print(cmd)
if len(cmd) != COMMAND_STRUCT.size:
    sys.exit(1)
lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(cmd)
print(lateral_airspeed_input)
lateral_airspeed = max(-30.0, min(30.0, lateral_airspeed_input))
drop_package_commanded = bool(drop_package_commanded_byte)
```

When I run it, I do still seem to get the desired result:

```
%> python2 p3.py

29.1000003815
```

So I must still be missing something here I think.

Comment: The one thing I notice that you're doing different is rather than using cmd = pilot.stdout.read you used cmd = sys.stdin.read. I think that's where the difference may lie. In my case, pilot is a subprocess defined as: 

pilot = subprocess.Popen(args.pilot, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

I believe I need to write to the stdout subprocess Pipe in script 2, as that is what is being read in script 1. Not too sure how to utilize this subprocess pipe though. Have been through quite a bit of documentation and still struggling.

Thanks so much for the help. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I mentioned it above, but in case you submit future questions to StackOverflow, that is key information to get into your question.  I interpreted pipe as `|` not `sys.stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.  If you can provide a fully functioning example that reproduces the issue, it saves on a lot of back & forth.

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom, I'll make sure to do so in my next StackOverflow post!!! Thanks again for the help :)