# Stdin and stdout in parralel

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, pipe

Good day all,

I would like to have 2 python scripts (let's call them p1 and p2) communicating with each other via a subprocess stdin/stdout pipeline. P1 will send to P2 via the stdin, and p2 will send to p1 via stdout. Now that also means P2 will read stdin to get what P1 is sending, and P1 will read stdout to get what p2 is sending. I have managed to send from P2 to P1 via stdout. I can make messages in p2 and send them to p1. However, I can't get P1 to send back to P2 via stdin even though I'm doing the same thing. Here is my p2 code:

```
COMMAND_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">fB3s")

TELEMETRY_STRUCT = struct.Struct(">Hhffb31B")

packed_data = struct.pack(">fB3s",19.1,1,b'3s')

#telemetry = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

#print(telemetry)

sys.stdout.buffer.write(packed_data)

sys.stdout.flush()
```

the sys.stdout.write and flush lines are responsible for writing the packed_data to the p1 script. Here is the relevant parts of the P1 script:

```
pilot = subprocess.Popen(args.pilot, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pilot.stdin.write(TELEMETRY_STRUCT.pack(int(loop_count * DT_SEC * 1e3) & 0xFFFF,
                                                    round(RECOVERY_X - vehicle.position[0]),
                                                    wind.vector[0],
                                                    wind.vector[1],
                                                    round((-vehicle.position[1] + WORLD_WIDTH_HALF) % WORLD_WIDTH -
                                                          WORLD_WIDTH_HALF),
                                                    *lidar_samples))
            #pilot.stdin.flush()
            loop_count += 1
            cmd = pilot.stdout.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
            if len(cmd) != COMMAND_STRUCT.size:
                result = CRASHED  # The pilot process must have 
                break
            lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(cmd)
            lateral_airspeed = max(-30.0, min(30.0, lateral_airspeed_input))
            print("speed", lateral_airspeed_input)
            print("drop", drop_package_commanded_byte)
            drop_package_commanded = bool(drop_package_commanded_byte)
```

However, if I go to P2 and uncomment the 2 telemetry lines, nothing prints and I get no data. Reading the stdin and then printing what comes out also blocks the program. If I comment out the stdout writing lines (the last 2 lines in p2) I still get no data. I understand that I have commented out pilot.stdin.flush() in the p1 script, but that's only done because I get an OS error when it is uncommented.

In p1, a subprocess (called pilot) is initiated to start the stdout and stdin pipes. How come I can write from p2 to p1 and read it and print it, but can't write from p1 to p2 and read it and print it.

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**

Just to further expand on the above. If P2 is as follows:

```
 packed_data = struct.pack(">fB3s",19.1,1,b'3s')
#telemetry = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
#print(telemetry, file = sys.stderr)

sys.stdout.buffer.write(packed_data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

and P1 is as follows:

```
            pilot = subprocess.Popen(args.pilot, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            pilot.stdin.write(TELEMETRY_STRUCT.pack(int(loop_count * DT_SEC * 1e3) & 0xFFFF,
                                                    round(RECOVERY_X - vehicle.position[0]),
                                                    wind.vector[0],
                                                    wind.vector[1],
                                                    round((-vehicle.position[1] + WORLD_WIDTH_HALF) % WORLD_WIDTH -
                                                          WORLD_WIDTH_HALF),
                                                    *lidar_samples))
            #pilot.stdin.flush()
            print("p1", wind.vector[0])
            loop_count += 1
            cmd = pilot.stdout.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
            if len(cmd) != COMMAND_STRUCT.size:
                result = CRASHED  # The pilot process must have 
                break
            lateral_airspeed_input, drop_package_commanded_byte, _ = COMMAND_STRUCT.unpack(cmd)
            lateral_airspeed = max(-30.0, min(30.0, lateral_airspeed_input))
            print("speed", lateral_airspeed_input)
            print("drop", drop_package_commanded_byte)
            drop_package_commanded = bool(drop_package_commanded_byte)
```

Then in p1 that first line works (the print("p1", Windvector) - i.e I can print the data correctly. The speed and drop print lines also work, indicating I am receiving data from P2. However, attempting to send the wind vector to p2 and reading it in p2 does not work. So can't send from p1 to p2 but I can send from p2 to p1.

Comment: You're getting deadlocked because output to pipes is buffered. You need to flush the buffer after each write.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm not to sure what you mean. In p2 I do sys.stdout.flush(). Does this not flush it?

Comment: I think you also need `pilot.stdin.flush()`, I'm not sure why it's getting an error. What's the error message?

Comment: Uncommenting it leads to this message:
  File "zip_sim.py", line 404, in <module>
    pilot.stdin.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument